# Uploading and downloading files in Java Spring 3.0 webservices

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, download

I'm searching for some good tutorials about implementations of uploading and downloading files (of different kind) in Java web services. I'd like to use latest Spring (core, context, web, webmvc), because I'm not into 'playing' with *.xml configuration files all the time ;). Unfortunately I managed to find only examples with writing own servlets. I’ve been told that easiest way for uploading is to use apache commons upload. Still I don't know an easy way for downloading.

I'd appreciate some example code or links to tutorials that would help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me google that for you "spring webservice upload file"

http://ltalbot.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/file-upload-using-rest-spring-mvc/

Comment: Thanks, I'm still pretty fresh with webservices.